# No se encuentra la clase PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2010

Tags: php, phpexcel

Estoy usando PHPExcel para generar reportes de Excel con PHP a partir de datos obtenidos de una base de datos MySQL.

Éste es el código que tengo:

```
<?php
    $conexion = new mysqli('localhost','root','admin123','database',3306);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("La conexión con el servidor de base de datos falló: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $consulta = "SELECT NIT, nombre_Cliente, telefono_Cliente, direccion_Cliente FROM cliente ORDER BY NIT";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
    if($resultado->num_rows > 0 ){

        date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');

        if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
            die('Este archivo solo se puede ver desde un navegador web');

        /** Se agrega la libreria PHPExcel */
        require_once 'lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';

        // Se crea el objeto PHPExcel
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

        // Se asignan las propiedades del libro
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Truji ;D") //Autor
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("CT") //Ultimo usuario que lo modificó
                             ->setTitle("Reporte Excel con PHP y MySQL")
                             ->setSubject("Reporte Excel con PHP y MySQL")
                             ->setDescription("Reporte de alumnos")
                             ->setKeywords("reporte clientes")
                             ->setCategory("Reporte excel");

        $tituloReporte = "Relación de clientes";
        $titulosColumnas = array('NIT', 'NOMBRE', 'TELEFONO', 'DIRECCION');

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->mergeCells('A1:D1');

        // Se agregan los titulos del reporte
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->setCellValue('A1',$tituloReporte)
                    ->setCellValue('A3',  $titulosColumnas[0])
                    ->setCellValue('B3',  $titulosColumnas[1])
                    ->setCellValue('C3',  $titulosColumnas[2])
                    ->setCellValue('D3',  $titulosColumnas[3]);

        //Se agregan los datos de los alumnos
        $i = 4;
        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->setCellValue('A'.$i,  $fila['NIT'])
                    ->setCellValue('B'.$i,  $fila['nombre_Cliente'])
                    ->setCellValue('C'.$i,  $fila['telefono_Cliente'])
                    ->setCellValue('D'.$i, utf8_encode($fila['direccion_Cliente']));
                    $i++;
        }

        $estiloTituloReporte = array(
            'font' => array(
                'name'      => 'Verdana',
                'bold'      => true,
                'italic'    => false,
                'strike'    => false,
                'size' =>16,
                    'color'     => array(
                        'rgb' => 'FFFFFF'
                    )
            ),
            'fill' => array(
                'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                'color' => array('argb' => 'FF220835')
            ),
            'borders' => array(
                'allborders' => array(
                    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE                    
                )
            ), 
            'alignment' =>  array(
                    'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
                    'vertical'   => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
                    'rotation'   => 0,
                    'wrap'          => TRUE
            )
        );

        $estiloTituloColumnas = array(
            'font' => array(
                'name'      => 'Arial',
                'bold'      => true,                          
                'color'     => array(
                    'rgb' => 'FFFFFF'
                )
            ),
            'fill'  => array(
                'type'      => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR,
                'rotation'   => 90,
                'startcolor' => array(
                    'rgb' => 'c47cf2'
                ),
                'endcolor'   => array(
                    'argb' => 'FF431a5d'
                )
            ),
            'borders' => array(
                'top'     => array(
                    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_MEDIUM ,
                    'color' => array(
                        'rgb' => '143860'
                    )
                ),
                'bottom'     => array(
                    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_MEDIUM ,
                    'color' => array(
                        'rgb' => '143860'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'alignment' =>  array(
                    'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
                    'vertical'   => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
                    'wrap'          => TRUE
            ));

        $estiloInformacion = new PHPExcel_Style();
        $estiloInformacion->applyFromArray(
            array(
                'font' => array(
                'name'      => 'Arial',               
                'color'     => array(
                    'rgb' => '000000'
                )
            ),
            'fill'  => array(
                'type'      => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                'color'     => array('argb' => 'FFd9b7f4')
            ),
            'borders' => array(
                'left'     => array(
                    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN ,
                    'color' => array(
                        'rgb' => '3a2a47'
                    )
                )             
            )
        ));

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:D1')->applyFromArray($estiloTituloReporte);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3:D3')->applyFromArray($estiloTituloColumnas);       
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setSharedStyle($estiloInformacion, "A4:D".($i-1));

        for($i = 'A'; $i <= 'D'; $i++){
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)            
                ->getColumnDimension($i)->setAutoSize(TRUE);
        }

        // Se asigna el nombre a la hoja
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Alumnos');

        // Se activa la hoja para que sea la que se muestre cuando el archivo se abre
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        // Inmovilizar paneles 
        //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->freezePane('A4');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(0,4);

        // Se manda el archivo al navegador web, con el nombre que se indica (Excel2007)
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Reportedeclientes.xlsx"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2010');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
        exit;

    }
    else{
        print_r('No hay resultados para mostrar');
    }
?>
```

Pero presenta el siguiente error:

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2010' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Reportes\lib\PHPExcel\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php:141
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Reportes\reporteexcel.php(204): PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter(Object(PHPExcel), 'Excel2010')
>
> #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Reportes\lib\PHPExcel\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php  on line 141

¿Por qué me sale ese error y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Esa librería esta depreciada,ahora esta disponible esta [https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) para su uso y es excelente. Saludos

Comment: voy a probarla a ver si sirve

Comment: Cual carperta es?

Comment: esa es la librería completa, lee la [documentación](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/) para su implementación y uso, te adelanto que se maneja con composer, yo la uso en mis proyectos con codeigniter y va de lujo

Comment: no funciona ya no genera el archivo

Comment: require_once 'PhpSpreadsheet-develop/src/PhpSpreadsheet/PHPExcel.php';

Comment: Aqui esta como implementarlo [INICIAR](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#getting-started) solo sigue las instrucciones y todo ira bien

Comment: tengo problemas con la instalacion del composer